# Do I need a visa to change from Heathrow airport to Gatwick airport?

Tags: uk, transit, airport-transfer, transit-visas

I would like to find out if I am traveling to the USA and would like to change airports from Heathrow to Gatwick, I will be in transit for less than 12 hours, but I have a USA visa and not a British visa is it possible? If not what steps should I follow to make it possible. I am in Gaborone, Botswana

Comment: Note that Gatwick and Heathrow are about 40 miles apart, so you'll definitely have to go through Immigration, and then catch a bus. If you need a Visa for the UK then you'll need a Visa for this.

Comment: @simonatrcl the UK generally permits holders of certain countries' visas, including those of the US, to participate in the "transit without visa" scheme, allowing those who would otherwise require a visa to pass immigration control without one.